# Detectar una palabra en textarea y enviar alerta JS

Tags: javascript

tengo la siguiente duda:

Tengo un **textarea** donde escribo informacion detallada de problemas o fallas, pero quiero lograr que cuando la persona escriba alguna de estas dos palabras "**Componente**" o "**Volado**" me haga un **alert** simplemente mostrando un mensaje.

Realmente no se por donde empezar, no se si alguien tiene algo similar o me pueda ayudar,

**Este es mi textarea:**

```
<textarea class="form-control areap" style="font-size: 12px" rows="2" id="problema" name="problema" placeholder="Escriba el problema" required></textarea>
```

Gracias.

Comment: Quieres detectar la palabra a secas o quieres saber si una frase contiene esa palabra?

Comment: pues me interesa que por ejemplo al ir escribiendo y el usuario la pone y la termina ahi mismo salga el alert como un recordatorio, no quiero que sea necesario enviar el formulario, si no el alert al instante

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los textareas soportan la propiedad `.value`, teniendo en cuenta que tu textarea tiene el ID "problema", puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera

```js
enviar.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (problema.value.toLowerCase() == "componente") {
        // Componente
        alert("componente")
    } else if (problema.value.toLowerCase() == "volado") {
        // volado
        alert("volado")
    } 
});
```

```html
<textarea class="form-control areap" style="font-size: 12px" rows="2" id="problema" name="problema" placeholder="Escriba el problema" required></textarea>
<button id="enviar">Enviar</button>
```

Con `addEventListener` capturaremos el evento de cuando se haga click en el botón enviar, y comprobaremos el valor del textarea, el `toLowerCase()` es para convertir lo que sea que haya ingresado el usuario en minúsculas

---

Si lo que buscas es detectar si el valor contiene las palabras que comentas, puedes usar `includes`

```js
enviar.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (problema.value.toLowerCase().includes("componente")) {
        // Componente
        alert("componente")
    } else if (problema.value.toLowerCase().includes("volado")) {
        // volado
        alert("volado")
    } 
});
```

```html
<textarea class="form-control areap" style="font-size: 12px" rows="2" id="problema" name="problema" placeholder="Escriba el problema" required></textarea>
```

La diferencia entre los dos es que el primero es para detectar un solo valor concreto, es decir que no funcionará si el valor es "componente hola mundo", mientras que en el otro bloque estás detectando si el valor incluye una palabra, el string anteriormente mencionado si funcionará en el segundo bloque de código

---

Basado en tus comentarios:

```js
problema.addEventListener("input", () => {
    if (problema.value.toLowerCase().includes("componente")) {
        // Componente
        alert("componente")
    } else if (problema.value.toLowerCase().includes("volado")) {
        // volado
        alert("volado")
    } 
});
```

```html
<textarea class="form-control areap" style="font-size: 12px" rows="2" id="problema" name="problema" placeholder="Escriba el problema" required></textarea>
```

En base a tu comentario:

```js
problema.addEventListener("input", () => {
    if (problema.value.toLowerCase() == "componente") {
        // Componente
        alert("componente")
    } else if (problema.value.toLowerCase() == "volado") {
        // volado
        alert("volado")
    } 
});
```

```html
<textarea class="form-control areap" style="font-size: 12px" rows="2" id="problema" name="problema" placeholder="Escriba el problema" required></textarea>
```

Comment: Esto se puede hacer sin tener que enviar? al ir escribiendo sobre el textarea

Comment: Claro, puedes cambiar `enviar` por `problema` y cambiar `"click"` por `"input"`

Comment: Tengo un problema y es que si quiero seguir escribiendo despues de esa palabra no deja de salir la alerta, tendra una solucion?

Comment: @EduardoMX Prueba con la modificación (el último bloque de código)

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias. Solucionado